# Rails - params not coming through from form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a very simple form_for with two text fields that has stopped sending the values through to the params hash. Here's the form:

```
<%= form_for @item, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :garment_type, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Garment type" %>
  <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Description" %>
<% end %>
```

There's no submit button because the form is submitted by jQuery. I've already tried submitting the form regularly and without AJAX but it didn't make a difference.

Here is the params hash once the form is submitted:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "item"=>{"garment_type"=>"", "description"=>""}, "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

As you can see it recognises that the fields were there, they're just empty.

The controller code:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    binding.pry
    @item = Item.create!(item_params)
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:garment_type, :description, :order_id)
  end
end
```

The generated HTML:

```
<form class="new_item" id="new_item" action="/items" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Garment type" type="text" name="item[garment_type]" id="item_garment_type">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Description" type="text" name="item[description]" id="item_description">
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
  var step = this.dataset.step;
  var nextStep = parseInt(step) + 1;

  $('#form-step-' + step).hide();
  $('#form-step-' + nextStep).show();
})

$('#next-1').click(function() {
  $('#new_item').submit(); 
})
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the controller's code?

Comment: Sure I've just added it. The only other thing in the controller currently is the item_params method.

Comment: does your model object `@item` has those attributes/columns? `garment_type` & `description`?

Comment: Thx. Can you show us the `item_params` method?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon yes it does

Comment: @maicher I've added all of the controller code

Comment: Thx. It looks good. Can you show the routes?

Comment: @maicher just `resources :items`

Comment: Can you post your `Item` model?

Comment: @Pavan empty other than `has_many :alterations`

Comment: Hmm.. It has to work then ;) How does the generated html look like? Can you share a screen of the generated html form?

Comment: Haha I know right? I added the generated HTML

Comment: Please share your jQuery code.

Comment: @Gerry I added the jQuery

Comment: Hmm, everything seems to be fine, have you tried to reproduce this behavior isolating just the form?